# Windows Phone Background Agents - Custom Control causing Unknown parser error: Scanner 2147500037

Tags: windows-phone, custom-controls, background-agents

I am attempting to use a custom control for a live tile in my background agent.  I have my live tiles successfully generating with user controls, but I now want to reference a custom control in my user control Xaml.  At design time everything looks correct, no errors and I see the custom control presented in the designer, but when I run the app and the background agent runs, I receive this error:

Unknown parser error: Scanner 2147500037

The position noted in the error is the location in the Xaml where I have my custom control.  If I remove the custom control the error goes away.

The custom control I am attempting to use (and its source code) can be found here:
http://blogs.u2u.net/diederik/post/2013/11/05/A-Modern-UI-radial-gauge-control-for-Windows-Phone-8-apps.aspx

I do not believe there are any references in this custom control to anything that cannot run in a background agent, so I am wondering if there is some limitation in general to using custom controls in background agents for windows phone?

If anyone has any ideas as to the cause of this error, please let me know.

Comment: What version are you trying to build this for? If this is a Silverlight control then it will not work in a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the control to work but refactored the code to implement the straight Xaml rather than using the control.  The end result is the same as what the control offered, but more complicated.